# Store a std::vector of gsl::span<T> not working as expected

Tags: c++, vector

I want to store some gls::span< std::complex>> in a std::vector. I expected it to be very simple:

```
vector<gsl::span<complex<double>>> allSpans; //Unexpected structure in debugger
vector<complex<double>> v{1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
gsl::span<complex<double>> span(v);
allSpans.push_back(span);
```

Inspecting allSpans in a debugger reveals that there is no normal vector structure for allSpans with elements as I would have expected, instead it shows me a _Mypair member only. I don't know where the problem lies.

Comment: Are you looking at a debug build or a release build?

Comment: Debug build. This is done with Qt Creator and the MSVC2017 Compiler.

Comment: Try an optimized release build. Performance is likely to increase greatly (although it will probably be *much* harder to debug).

Comment: But the program is not working they way it should be. I need a vector of spans, instead I get something else, no Idea what exactly that is.

Comment: Please show a compilable program, the command you are using to compile it, what exactly you are typing in the debugger, the output you are seeing, and what are you expecting to see instead.